# Android service called data from list multiple times

Tags: java, android

***1.hello, I have created service for Schedule message but the problem is i have set the loop in my service method but it send the message all the message that is set on list.***

***2.I want to set the loop like, send message on list will be send at least ones time.***

***3.And the message has been sent is not send again.***

//***Here is my code.***
//MyService class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class SchedulerMsgService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private ArrayList<schedulerDetails> myschedule = new ArrayList<schedulerDetails>();
    private String phoneNo, message, sDate, curTime;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "oNsTART IS rEADY ");
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        final List<schedulerDetails> ScheduleList = mDbHelper.selectAllNumbers();
        for (int j = 0; j < ScheduleList.size(); j++) {
            myschedule.add(ScheduleList.get(j));
            phoneNo = myschedule.get(j).num;
            message = myschedule.get(j).textMessage;
            sDate = myschedule.get(j).date;
            curTime = myschedule.get(j).time;

            sendSMS(phoneNo, message, sDate, curTime);
        }


        Toast.makeText(this, "condition Matched", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Toast.makeText(this, "condition Not Matched",
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public void sendSMS(String phoneNo, String message, String sDate,
            String curTime) {
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
                SENT), 0);
        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Sent",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic Failure",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null Service",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio Off",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not Delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the message has been sent, then remove the number from your database or add some information in the database that the message has been sent. Then `mDbHelper.selectAllNumbers()` can return only the numbers that need to receive the message.

Comment: sir i have try to sent message deleted but the problem is that now in list send only last set record message in list. 

i want to send all message in list which have not yet time for sent 

For Example if the two message set in the list which have been set time like 2 pm and the another have set the time like 2-03 pm i want to sent all message in list but in my case it send only last message set insted of both.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the conditions you have to send / not send messages - update your question and try to describe that with examples. -- But once `ScheduleList` contains the list and no information if that message has to be sent or not then you can't stop it from sending in the code you posted. You have to change the logic that generates this list to fit your needs.